# Marketing Cloud Dynamic Content - Tracking

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

supposed that you have an email built with dynamic content.

The mail shows 6 different contents for the body, based on a field.  Is it possible to track opens and clicks for every different content?

Thanks at all,

Erika

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic content tracking requires the following AMPscript functions BeginImpressionRegion() and EndImpressionRegion(). If you use the out of the box Dynamic Content block in Content Builder within SFMC these AMPscript functions should be auto generated. If you are coding AMPscript manually then you will have to manually and correctly add these AMPscript functions.

In the EDM the correct syntax looks like:

```
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("*Name of Impression region to track")=%%

<!--HTML CONTENT HERE -->

%%=EndImpressionRegion(0)=%%
```

Check this resource out for more details:
https://ampscript.guide/beginimpressionregion/

And check this one for a more involved example/answer:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185629/impression-tracking-how-do-i-structure-in-ampscript
take care